# Image gets uploaded 4 times on Firebase Storage

Tags: image, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I run into an issue and don't know where is the root cause.
When I upload image to Firebase Storage, it get uploaded 4 times, I don't know why?
Here is my code:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == ALEGE_POZA
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            selectedPhotoUri = data!!.data
            alertDialog.show()
            uploadFile()
                alertDialog.dismiss()
}
}

private fun uploadFile() {

        if (selectedPhotoUri == null) return
  var filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        var reff = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("/pozeBlog/$filename")
        var bitearrayoutstr:ByteArrayOutputStream=ByteArrayOutputStream()
        var uritobtm:Bitmap=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context!!.contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)
        uritobtm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50,bitearrayoutstr )

        val data =bitearrayoutstr.toByteArray()

        reff.putBytes(data)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                if (it != null) {
                    reff.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<Uri> ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {

                            var url = task.result.toString()

                          mDb!!.child("poze").push().setValue(url)

                            if (pozapost != null) {
                                Picasso.get().load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.logor).fit().centerCrop().into(pozapost)
                            } else {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

The image is uploaded 4 times 2 times by 2 sizes:
eg:2 images at 135kb & 2 images at 155 kb

Comment: post the code where you call `uploadFile()`

Comment: My bad i was uploading 2 times by mistake!!